# How do I say 'It feels like'?

Tags: english-to-german

How do I say ' It feels like' in German? I want to say it in this context: The time over here is 4 in the afternoon, but it feels like 9 in the evening.

Mein Versuch ist : Die Uhr ist 16 Uhr, aber es sieht aus, als ob es 22 Uhr wäre.

Comment: "Die Uhr ist 16 Uhr ..." - neiin! "Es ist (gerade mal) 16 Uhr ..."

Comment: http://www.dict.cc/?s=it+looks+like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except that is should be "Die Uhr zeigt 16 Uhr" or just "Es ist 16 Uhr", your translation is correct in this special context, because you usually say something like this after looking at the sky or how dark it already is. Other possibilites that are more general would be the literal translation

> ... aber es fühlt sich an, als ob ...

or

> ... aber es wirkt, als ob ...